# HTTP service in AR1220

Tags: networking

I have a router AR1220 VRP V200R001C01SPC500. I'm trying to enable the http service to configure this way, but the command doesn't exist. It a problem with the version? from which version are available this feature?

Answer (score 0):

I've recently manage to configure web mgmt on 2 [AR1200](http://www.huanetwork.com/index.php?main_page=advanced_search_result&inc_subcat=1&search_in_description=1&keyword=%20AR1200) with this version:
AR1200 V200R002C01SPC200
you can download it from support - is general available.
I know that some earlier versions support web mgmt but in chinese so i think you should download and upgrade to AR1200 V200R002C01SPC200 in order to be sure.
Best Regards